# C++ Stack Implementation, checking parenthesis correctness

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack, push, parentheses

I want to give the expression in the form of parenthesis through CIN, like: `())`. then, through push & pop operation of the stack, I want the program to print me weather the given expression is BALANCED or NOT. The program works perfectly but only one issue has been found & that is when I enter like `()(`, so it tells me that this expression is IMBALANCED which is fine but when I enter like `() (`, so then it tell me that this expression is BALANCED which is actually not balanced.

```
#include <iostream>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
using namespace std;

char Stack[10];
int top=-1;

void push(char ch)
{
    if(top<10)
    {
        top++;
        Stack[top] = ch;
    }
    else
        cout<<"Stack Overflow";
}

void pop()
{
    if(top > -1)
    {
        top--;
    }
    else
        cout<<"Stack Underflow";    
}
int show(){
    cout<<"It is imbalanced.";
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    
    int a=0,b=0;
    string exp;
    cout << "Write down the parenthesis:" ;
    cin >> exp;
    bool check = true;
    
    for(int i=0; i<exp.length(); i++)
    {
        if(exp[i]== '(')
        {
            push(exp[i]);
        }
        else if(exp[i]== ')')
        {
            if(top == -1)
            {
                check = false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                pop();
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<exp.length(); i++)
    {
        if(exp[i]=='('){
        ++a;
    }
    else if (exp[i]==')')
    {
        b++;
        
        }   
    }
    
    if(a>b){
        cout<<"\n\nGiven Combination is IMBALANCED";
        return 0;
    }
    
    if(check == true)
        cout<<"\n\nGiven Combination is BALANCED";
    
    else
        cout<<"\n\nGiven Combination is IMBALANCED";
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't you want to check if check is true and the stack is empty to see if its balanced otherwise it is imbalanced. I don't think the end loop where you count ( and ) is the correct solution.

Comment: This computation does not need a stack.

Comment: Well, add an `else` branch to skip spaces then.

Comment: Your bug for `() (`  is `cin >> exp;` remember that `cin >> exp;` reads up to the first whitespace character so when you typed `() (` you read only `()` which is balanced. I did not see that at first but debugged here: [https://onlinegdb.com/pji0k1cHZS](https://onlinegdb.com/pji0k1cHZS) and saw it in a few seconds after putting a breakpoint on line 50 and adding the `() (` as the input text.

Answer (score 1):

The main comments boil down to:

- Don’t use a stack when no stack is needed.

  - And if you do use one, don’t limit it to an arbitrary fixed depth.
- Handle errors and report malformed expressions.
- Make sure you get the right input; `std::getline()` may be less error-prone than input tokenized using the `>>` operators. Just skip spaces (or whatever insignificant characters are allowed in the input).
- `using namespace std;` is an antipattern and a bad habit.

The basic idea: Calculate the nesting `depth` as you iterate over the string. It must be zero, ultimately. It must **not** drop below zero at any point.

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

using std::size_t;

bool correctly_parenthesized(std::string_view expression) {
  size_t depth{0};
  for (const auto character : expression) {
    switch (character) {
      case '(': ++depth; break;
      case ')': if (depth) { --depth; break; } else { return false; }
      case ' ': break;
      default: throw std::invalid_argument("invalid character");
    }
  }
  return depth == 0;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Write down the parentheses: ";
  std::string exp;
  std::getline(std::cin, exp);
  try {
    std::cout << (correctly_parenthesized(exp) ? "YES" : "NO") << std::endl;
  } catch (const std::exception &e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
}
```